# How can I modify the shortcut/hotkey "description" in a swing JMenu item?

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar

Our swing application uses the "spacebar" key as a shortcut key.  In other words, if you press the spacebar anywhere within the application window, it will perform a certain behaviour.   What's more, this same behaviour can also be performed by using a JMenuItem in the window's menu bar.

The normal way to implement this is to simply set "spacebar" as the "ACCELERATOR_KEY" for the corresponding JMenuItem, and just let swing take care of the rest.   Unfortunately, we can't do this, because if we set "spacebar" as the ACCELERATOR_KEY, the shortcut fires every time the user hits spacebar, even at bad times, like when the user is typing regular text in a textfield inside the application window.

To get around that problem, we've implemented the spacebar as a window-level pseudo shortcut key WITHOUT properly installing it in the corresponding JMenuItem as an ACCELERATOR-KEY.   It's working fine, except of course **the JMenuItem does not have any shortcut key "hint" on it**.  That is, the menu item should say "spacebar" in little grey letters right on the menu item, so that our users can "discover" the shortcut key without reading the user manual.

But the text is missing since it only gets added to the menu item when you install the shortcut as an ACCELERATOR-KEY.

So my question is:  **How can I modify that shortcut key hint text on our JMenuItem, so that I can add the appropriate "hint" myself**?   It would be nice if I could do this without having to mess around at the Look-and-Feel level, since our application is multiplatform and uses several different LAFS.

Comment: For what its worth, this is a bad idea. Using a common key for a shortcut "sometimes" is bad UI design. There is a reason shortcuts use meta-keys (ctrl, alt, shift). It keeps a user from unintentionally firing the shortcut. Using the spacebar as the shortcut, but only under certain circumstances, will be confusing for your users. My 2-cents.

Comment: iTunes does it and people don't seem to mind that much.

Comment: @Nemi:  I agree with you in general principle, but in this case we are an exception.  Our software assists with a very repetitive task, and it requires the user to activate a certain behaviour at irregular but very frequent intervals.  The hotkey gets uses so frequently that having to press a modifier key in addition to the hotkey actually is an undesirable extra burden.  We even chose the spacebar for this key because it is extra big and easy to hit with either hand!

Comment: I think this is often a legitimate practice, as long as the action is almost instantaneous and easily reversible. I've seen single key shortcuts used in 3D animation packages like Blender to great effect. It's unfortunate that it's not supported more directly in swing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions, guys.   This discussion has led me to a couple of different solutions that work.

First, to solve the problem of displaying shortcut "hint" text without actually having a working shortcut key.  Just add the shortcut key to the Action/JMenuItem as normal (this will give you your hint text) and then simply unbind the shortcut key right after it has been added.   An easy (but not the only) way to do this is to create a subclass of JMenuItem, and override a single method:

```
   @Override public void setAccelerator( KeyStroke keyStroke ) {
      super.setAccelerator( keyStroke );
      getInputMap( WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW ).put( keyStroke, "none" );
   }
```

Voila!  A non-functional shortcut key, with the hint text on the menu item still intact.

---

A better solution to my original problem, however, is to change the behaviour of all shortcut keys so that they *do not fire when the keyboard focus is inside a text component.*  As far as I can tell, that is really the only situation where an (unmodified) shortcut key like SPACE would collide with the behaviour of an existing window component.   This second solution is a bit more effort, but it's betteron because it allows me to remove all my other custom code for handling the shortcut key without installing it in the JMenuBar.

Instead, I can just use the regular shortcut key architecture in swing (i.e. install it in the JMenuBar or Action object) with only a single minor modification:

This part is in a custom subclass of JMenuItem again:

```
   /** {@inheritDoc} */
   @Override public void setAccelerator( KeyStroke keyStroke ) {
      super.setAccelerator( keyStroke );
      if ( doClickAction_ == null ) {
         doClickAction_ = new DoClickAction( getActionMap().get( "doClick" ) );
         getActionMap().put("doClick", doClickAction_);
      }
   }
```

And this is a new private inner class in my JMenuItem subclass:

```
   /**
    * This action wraps the original "doClick" action for this menu item,
    * altering it so that it only fires if the keyboard focus is not in any
    * kind of text area or text field.
    * 
    * This allows accelerator keys to be added to {@link IMenuItem}s,
    * but the user can still type those keys into text components without 
    * triggering the accelerator key behaviour.
    */
   private static class DoClickAction extends AbstractAction {

      // the original action, i.e. that we are wrapping
      private final Action doClickAction_;

      DoClickAction( Action doClickAction ) {
         if ( doClickAction == null ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
         }
         doClickAction_ = doClickAction;
      }

      @Override public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
         final KeyboardFocusManager kfm = 
            KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
         if ( kfm.getFocusOwner() instanceof JTextComponent == false ) {
            doClickAction_.actionPerformed( e );
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking into consideration your requirement not to touch the L&F code, which is where the accelerator text is laid out...

Looking at the code for `JMenuItem`, it seems that you could create a subclass of `JMenutItem` for your "spacebar" item, which would override the `setAccelerator` method to assign the accelerator keyStroke, but not go through the configuration of the action.  This should allow for the UI code to do its job of laying out the menu as you like it, without the pesky action being triggered when your users are actually trying to put spaces between their words (do they really need to do that anyway?).

Comment: Hmmm this sounds promising, thank you for the reply.

I suppose the only problem with this would be that the JMenuItem itself would stop working properly...i.e. if the user clicked on it with the mouse instead of using the shortcut key, the action would still not be properly attached.

There might be a way to work around that in there too, though...this is a good starting point. :)

Comment: I think the menu item should work with the mouse in the above 'solution.'  It is only the keyStroke accelerator that you are mucking around with.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if text components are the only component that causes a problem. If so, then maybe you can just customize the Action to use the KeyboardFocusManager to determine which component currently has focus. If it is a text component then you don't invoke your Action.

Comment: Yes, this is basically what I did, though I customized the JMenuItem instead, because I'm reusing my new JMenuItem in other places.

Answer (score 0):

Does setting the accelerator interfere with the way you've currently implemented it all?  If not you could just set the accelerator to the space bar... I am going to go ahead and assume you can't do that.  The other thing you could do is override the getAccelerator() on your JMenuItem, so you don't have to copy most of the code from JMenuItem (not that there is much there).

```
JMenuItem clickSpace = new JMenuItem("Item With Accelerator Hint -->") {
        @Override
        public KeyStroke getAccelerator()
        {
            return KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0);
        }
    }
```